# Centering form in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, html, forms

I'm developing an open-source social-network for a student-group &etc.

I want this form to be centred on the page.

My attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/WgSgW/

**How do I get it centred?** - The closest I've gotten to a working solution is using the `offset#` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your form container, `.span9` with `.span12` to fully expand that row across the screen, then simply define your log in table as `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center` all the content of your form, like so:

Created my own classes to not mess around with the bootstrap's default values.

**CSS**

```
.login {
    text-align:center;
}

.center {
    *display:inline; /* ie 7 */
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left; /* to reset the alignment to the left, container will remain centered */
    zoom:1; /* ie7 junk */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 login">
            <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <table class="center">
                    <tr id="auth_user_email__row">
                        <td class="w2p_fl"><label for="auth_user_email" id="auth_user_email__label" style="display:none;">Email: </label></td><td class="w2p_fw">
                        <input class="string" id="auth_user_email" name="email" placeholder="email address" type="text" value="" />
                        </td><td class="w2p_fc"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="auth_user_password__row">
                        <td class="w2p_fl"><label for="auth_user_password" id="auth_user_password__label" style="display:none;">Password: </label></td><td class="w2p_fw">
                        <input class="password" id="auth_user_password" name="password" placeholder="password" type="password" value="" />
                        </td><td class="w2p_fc"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="submit_record__row">
                        <td class="w2p_fl"></td><td class="w2p_fw">
                        <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Signup" />
                        </td><td class="w2p_fc"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-centered">
        By signing up you are agreeing to our <a href="/legal/agreement/">terms &amp; conditions</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WgSgW/1/

Comment: Thanks, I'm ready to accept this answer. Before I do though, is there a way to also centre the input areas?

Comment: @AT yes, just remove the `text-align:left;` property from the `.center` class. I placed it in there to reset the positioning of the elements.

Comment: Great, thanks. Will test later today.

Answer (score 0):

The native way for positioning elements in Twitter Bootstrap is using `offset#` classes. For your particular case, you can use

```
<div class="span4 offset4"> ... </div>
```

Taje a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/simbirsk/Yc52b/)

Comment: Yeah, I know I can get it working with the `offset#` classes, but I thought that there may be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The form is already centered. What you need to do is center the table by applying style `margin:0 auto;`

this should work.